# Conditionally render date state variable in JSX Text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, datetimepicker

I am trying to build functionality for users to select a date using `DateTimePickerModal`. Before anything is selected, there should be a clickable message saying "Select date" which is then replaced by the selected date afterwards. I am not sure if there is a standard way to do this, but I was thinking of conditionally rendering `Text` like so:

```
const AddActivityScreen = props => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    
    const showMode = currentMode => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
    };

    const showDatepicker = () => {
        showMode('date');
    };

    const handleConfirm = (date) => {
        setStartDate(date);
        hidePicker();
    };

    const hidePicker = () => {
        setShow(false);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <DateTimePickerModal 
                isVisible={show}
                mode={mode}
                onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                onCancel={hidePicker}
            />
            <View>
                { startDate ? (
                    <Text onPress={showDatepicker}>{startDate}</Text> // something is going wrong here!
                ) : (
                    <Text onPress={showDatepicker}>Select a date</Text>
                )}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Everything works until I select a date, when I get the following error message:

[image: DateTimePicker error]

Comment: You're rendering a Date inside Text, which accepts only strings. Try doing `startDate.toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker#available-props) of the package you are using, the returned `date` is a standard date object.

If you want to render it, you have to convert it into a string first, by using the appropriate formatting method.

For example :

```
<View>
     <Text onPress={showDatepicker}>{startDate ? startDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US") : "Select a date"}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks! Bonus points if you can tell me why the `DateTimePickerModal` reopens after I select a date and then closes after I select a date again. Discussion linked [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker/issues/54) but I am not using Formik.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, objects cannot be rendered as children of a component. My guess is `handleConfirm` function is setting the start date to an object instead of a string. I'll suggest trying to convert it to string with something like:

```
<Text onPress={showDatepicker}>{JSON.stringify(startDate)}</Text>
```